# Coloring of circle with 12 sections

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, coloring

> We have a circle with 12 (equally sized) sections. In how many ways can you color the circle if we consider two results similar if you can get one from the other by rotating the circle? (I'm looking for a formula dependent on the number of colors.)

I have done a similar exercise before with a cube, so here is what I have so far.

Let us define:

- $X$ ... all the ways you can color the circle in a fixed position
- equivalence $x\sim y$ $\iff$ one result can be obtained from the other by rotating the circle
- $G$ ... ways to rotate the circle
- $\mathrm{Fix}_g$ = $\{x \in X \mid xg = x\}$

And now I believe the formula should be:
$$|X /\!\sim|={\sum_{g\in G}|\mathrm{Fix}_g| \over |G|}.$$

But how do I calculate $G$ and $\mathrm{Fix}_g$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must determine how every permutation of $G$ contributes to the cycle index. The identity, for example, fixes all $12$ sections: this contributes $t_1^{12}$. There are two permutations that send all the elements through $6$-cycles (namely, rotating two spaces clockwise or counterclockwise): these contribute $2t_6^2$. So the cycle index will be
$$\frac1{|G|}(t_1^{12} + 2t_6^2 + \cdots) = \frac1{12}(t_1^{12} + 2t_6^2 + \cdots)$$
You can go through the remaining permutations to complete the above expression.

Finally, this expression can be reduced to what you're looking for by setting all the $t_i$ to be equal; we get
$$\frac1{12}(t^{12} + 2t^2 + \cdots)$$

Have a look at the [Wikipedia article on Pólya counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem) for more examples.

Comment: the $t$ here means the number of colors, right?

Comment: @Alternatic Yes, that's right. Once you get the full polynomial, try evaluating it at $t=1$: with only one colour, there's only one colouring, so you should get $\frac{12}{12} = 1$.